# Sum up same objects with the QGIS composer atlas filter

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have a line layer.
Atlas shall filter by a number column.
Many of the lines have the same number like this: 500, 500, 500, 520, 530, 530.

Now Atlas makes an own image for any 500, when I try to save my work.
How can I sum up all 500 to get only one image instead of three?
Can I use somehow count_distinct?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: The only thing I could do is to highlight all "500" together in the canvas with "Nummer" = attribute( @atlas_feature , 'Nummer'), but in the Altas all lines are still individually selectable

Answer (score 1):

Use the Singlepart to Multipart tool to aggregate all lines with the same numeric value into one multipart feature. Use the result layer as input for Atlas.

Comment: thats a solution, but why does qgis select all unique numbers with "Nummer" = attribute( @atlas_feature , 'Nummer') in a rule based style and can't it in the atlas?

Comment: @Chenshi Two different features, two different logics